# How to use string format on a list item

Tags: c#, list, string-formatting, drawstring

I'm using drawstring to get a item from a list to be displayed, but now i would like it to be displayed as a 4 digit number instead of a single digit.

So instead of it displaying `0` i would like it to display `0.000` . If anyone could help me with this that would be nice.

This is the list type used.

```
List<string> ListVrd = new List<string>();
```

The code used to fill the list.

```
c = drART["MVRD"].ToString();
ListVrd.Add(c);
```

And the line of code used to print the item.

```
row = ListVrd[itemsPrinted];
e.Graphics.DrawString(row, DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, distance, currentY);//print item
```

Comment: The top line sets row from `ListVrd` and the bottom uses `ListSgr`.. are these the same?

Comment: seems like i copied the wrong list on the bottom, but its not the biggest of diffrence since its only the list name. but thanks for pointing out that mistake in my question ill change it now.

Comment: How do you populate `ListVrd`?

Comment: The whole DrawString part is irrelevant, it's about where/how you fill the List<string>. And that code is not posted.

Comment: `0.ToString("F3")` -> `0.000`

Comment: What is `drART`? What data types could be returned by indexer?

Comment: drART is the datareader i use for the sql query. the field it gets a value from is a of a Integer type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to make it work using some of the things suggested here and some the msdn list of the format placeholders I managed to get what I wanted.

This is the code im using now.

```
c = drART["MVRD"].ToString();
c2 = (String.Format("{0:###,###0,000} ", Convert.ToInt32(c), cult));
ListVrd.Add(c2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume what is coming from `drART` is a number, in which case you can format it there:

```
c = ((float)drART["MVRD"]).ToString("0.000");
ListVrd.Add(c);
```

Note that the above assumes that the number coming from `drART["MVRD"]` is a `float`. Check what type it *actually* is - it may be `int`,`decimal`,`long` etc.

See [Standard formatting strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Custom formatting strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If I try that it gives me this error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @maam27 - you need to first cast the result from `drART` to the right type. Ill update answer

Comment: What would I use for numeric? I tried the code with a int but if I go for that it would give me this: "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: Use decimal data type and you can format like this `1001.2511415M.ToString("n3")`

Comment: @Eric the data inside the database is a integer value, i dont really have any use for a decimal number since it only has full digits.

Comment: @maam27 Which do you mean 10 --> 10.00 or 10.000?

Comment: The field is supposed to show the minimal amount that should be stored of a item. for most of them the minimum is 0 but i want to have it displayed as 0.000 and 0.001 for when it would be 1 etc.

Comment: @maam27 - It helps us answer your question if you actually ask the right question and provide the right details. You never specified anything about turning `1` into `0.001` - how were we meant to know that? Also, specifying that the value in the database is an integer saves a whole lot of guesswork.

Comment: What about `string.Format("{0:n3}", 99999 / 1000m)`? Will broke your 4 digit  limit if minimal amount > 9999

Answer (score -2):

You'll need to convert the `string` to a numerical type and then convert that back to a `string` in the desired format, e.g.

```
formattedString = Convert.ToDouble(unformattedString).ToString("n3");
```

Where you actually do the conversion is up to you, i.e. before you add the item to the list or when you take it out.  I have to wonder though, if the data represents a number then why is it stored as a `string` in the first place?

Comment: It's absurd. Instead converting a number to a proper string, when filling the list, you're offering a double conversion.

Comment: @Dennis, it's an answer to the question that was asked.  There's also no need to use both parts of the conversion.  The "double conversion" contains two single conversions so, if you have a number (which I specifically alluded to) then you obviously only have to use the second one.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the question was updated shortly after you posted this.